# How to calculate effect size usisng statsmodels.stats.power

Tags: statistics

I ran this code in python

```
power_analysis = smp.TTestIndPower()
power_analysis.solve_power(
        nobs1=143293, 
        power=0.8, 
        alpha=0.05, 
        ratio=1.0*143398/143293,
        alternative='two-sided'
    )
```

The output is = 0.01046481401112572

Is the output effect size?  Can the effect size be calculated even without the standard deviation and mean of sample 1, 2?